# Multiclass Classifiers

Tags: neural-network, classification, svm, decision-tree

I am working on a audio multi class classification problem (noise,vessels,2 types of animals) by using MFCC features. I am getting different results with different classifiers. I tried Bayesian type, Artificial Neural Networks, MSVM and decision trees.

Can anybody tell me what are the strengths and weaknesses of each of those 4 classifiers?

Many thanks

Comment: Are you sure this is the right community for this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no “best” classifier
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_free_lunch_theorem

Averaged over all possible types of data distributions,
all classifi ers perform the same. Th us, we cannot say which algorithm
... is the “best”. Over any given data distribution or set of
data distributions, however, there is usually a best classifi er. Th us, when
faced with real data it’s a good idea to try many classifi ers. Consider
your purpose: Is it just to get the right score, or is it to interpret the
data? Do you seek fast computation, small memory requirements, or
confi dence bounds on the decisions? Diff erent classifi ers have diff erent
properties along these dimensions.

[Learning OpenCV](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596516130.do) page 465